# An unexpected exception happened in thread AWT-EventQueue-0 / Netbeans Install

Tags: java, netbeans, installation

After encountering a bug in my Netbeans 8.2, i tried to reinstall it. However, installation always stops with the following message:

[image]

I copied the content of the log to Pastebin, as it exceeded Stackoverflows 30k character limit.
https://pastebin.com/raw/tdrUGKhE
I think this is the most relevant part:

```
[2017-11-15 10:07:59.153]: An unexpected exception happened in thread AWT-EventQueue-0
[2017-11-15 10:07:59.154]: java.lang.NullPointerException
[2017-11-15 10:07:59.154]:  at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.access$200(Unknown Source)
[2017-11-15 10:07:59.154]:  at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$1.call(Unknown Source)
[2017-11-15 10:07:59.154]:  at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$1.call(Unknown Source)
[2017-11-15 10:07:59.154]:  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
[2017-11-15 10:07:59.154]:  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
[2017-11-15 10:07:59.154]:  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
[2017-11-15 10:07:59.154]:  at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2$ComInvoker$3.run(Unknown Source)
[2017-11-15 10:07:59.154]:  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[2017-11-15 10:07:59.155]: ... show message dialog
[2017-11-15 10:07:59.155]:     title: Critical Error
[2017-11-15 10:07:59.155]:     message: An unexpected exception happened in thread AWT-EventQueue-0
[2017-11-15 10:07:59.155]:     
[2017-11-15 10:07:59.155]:     Exception:
[2017-11-15 10:07:59.155]:       java.lang.NullPointerException:
[2017-11-15 10:07:59.155]:       null
```

Trying to install Netbeans 7.0.1 with Java 6 or using the Netbeans + JDK bundle gives similar results.

EDIT:
Solved it! Something from Java must've been installed on a Network drive, which i couldn't access without connecting using a VPN. Installation was succesfull after connecting to the network.

Answer (score 1):

if anyone is still looking for a solution to this error, I found the I was missing an entry on my regedit, I just added the following key and it worked.

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace{F02C1A0D-BE21-4350-88B0-7367FC96EF3C}

[Regedit Picture, missing entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1aXu.png)